# Что я делаю не так с запросами SQL в LARAVEL?

Tags: php, sql, laravel

Собственно, вот моя функция контроля флуда.

```
public function StopFlud($user)
{
    $search_user =\DB::table('stop_flud') 
                ->where('User_id', $user)->first(); // Ищем пользователя в базе
                if(empty($search_user)) // Если пользователя нет в базе, то создаём строку с временем его последней ставки
                {
                 \DB::table('stop_flud')->insertGetId(['User_id' => $user, 'last_date' => time()]);
                }
                else { // Иначе просто подгружаем ему время последней ставки

                if((time()-$search_user->last_date) < 2) // Если прошло меньше 2 секунд c момента его последней ставки, то FALSE
                {
                    return 'false';
                }
                else 
                {
                \DB::table('stop_flud')
                ->where('User_id', $user)
                ->update(['last_date' => time()]);
                    return 'true';

                }
                }

}
```

В итоге, функция не работает. Что я делаю не так? два часа уже над ней сижу

Comment: а зачем вам отдельная таблица, если у вас уже есть таблица Users. Почему нельзя там создать столбец отдельный?

Comment: @n.osennij потому что, мне именно так нужно.

Comment: а не использовать все преимущества Eloquent и не городить бог знает что - это тоже так нужно?

Comment: вы хотите, чтобы пользователь не чаще чем раз в какое-то время мог оставить комментарий?

Comment: какая у вас версия фреймворка?

Comment: комментарии у вас через API\ajax или через http?

Comment: @n.osennij, что-то типа того. К сожалению, я не знаком с Eloquent.

Comment: @n.osennij у меня есть две кнопки, который исполняют свои функции. Я хочу сделать, что бы ими можно было пользоваться не чаще, чем раз в две секунды

Answer (score 2):

Для ограничения используйте встроенный middleware - [trottle](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#rate-limiting). Таким образом можно ограничить количество запросов в заданное время к определённому роуту. При этом ограничение работает для каждого отдельного юзера.

Пример из документации

> For example, let's specify that an authenticated user may access the
>   following group of routes 60 times per minute:

```
Route::middleware('auth:api', 'throttle:60,1')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/user', function () {
        //
    });
});
```

К роуту применяется два middleware, один из которых - количество запросов в минуту. В данном случае не более 60 в минуту.

В вашем случае примерно так (если группа роутов)

```
Route::middleware('throttle:1,0.03')->group(function () {
    Route::post('/action', 'IndexController@action');
});
```

Или так, если только один

```
Route::post('/action', 'IndexController@action')->middleware('throttle:1,0.03');
```

Comment: очень полезно, спасбо, но а как сделать 1 раз в 2 секунды через это?

Comment: @RomanKashirov делить умеете?

Comment: Спасибо, дружище

Comment: Хотя нет, подожди. У меня Ajax передаёт `data: type` для отдельной функции по `Route::post('action', 'IndexController@action');` Дальше в функции `if($r->type == betMin)` или `if(($r->type == betMax)`. то есть мне нужно на конкретные строки в функции сделать флуд контроль

Comment: Ну разделите роуты. Каждый метод класса - может быть отдельным роутом. Я без понятия, что вы и как там делаете.

Comment: `Route::middleware('auth:api', 'throttle:60,1')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/user', function () {
        //
    });
});` Хорошо, я просто с Laravel не силён вообще, объясните пожалуйста как, конкретно вашим методом сделать мой роут `Route::post('/action', 'IndexController@action');` Я просто не понимаю аргументы, который он принимает, например auth:api - Это что?

Comment: я же написал что это - `К роуту применяется два middleware, один из которых - количество запросов в минуту. В данном случае не более 60 в минуту.`

Comment: Если я в моём случае делаю вот так вот в Route.php:
`Route::middleware('auth:api', 'throttle:1,1/5')->group(function () {
     Route::post('/action', 'IndexController@action');
});`
То ajax не видит куда отправлять запрос

Comment: потому что вы применяете второй middleware - 'auth:api'. Читайте документацию. Делать сайт и ничего не изучать - гиблое дело. Курсы посмотрите хотя бы. Целуй курс вот - https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl_kpL5cwH6LLuvd_xXOplXejM7shFhme

Comment: n.osennij ладно, спасибо вам большое, в любом случае. Я благодарен.

Comment: У меня нет нет `throttle`
Вот:
    `protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
  'access' => \App\Http\Middleware\Access::class,
    ];`

Comment: у вас настолько старая версия фреймворка? Не хотите обновиться?

Comment: Я боюсь, что всё собьётся, я же не опытный в этих делах.

Comment: Может всё таки можно реализовать мой код?